# QGridLayout addWidget(CustomWidget) is not working

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm using the `QGridLayout` in my code, and want to add my custom widget to gridlayout, it's not working with `addWidget(CustomWidget*)`.

This is runing on Windows10 with Visual Studio 2013 and Qt5.6.3.

```
// *.h
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
private:
    Ui::MainWindow ui;
};

class CustomWidget : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    CustomWidget(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR) : QWidget(parent) {}
    ~CustomWidget() {}
};

// *.cpp
// when i use CustomWidget
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {
    ui.setupUi(this);

    QWidget *grid = new QWidget(this);
    grid->setStyleSheet("background:pink;");
    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout(grid);
    layout->setMargin(0);
    layout->setSpacing(0);
    grid->setLayout(layout);
    grid->setGeometry(500, 150, 240, 180);

    // following code is not working, when run this program, 
    // i can only see the 'grid' widget with pink background
    CustomWidget *w = new CustomWidget(grid);
    w->setStyleSheet("background:red;");
    layout->addWidget(w, 0, 0);
}

// but if i use QWidget
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {
    ui.setupUi(this);

    QWidget *grid = new QWidget(this);
    grid->setStyleSheet("background:pink;");
    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout(grid);
    layout->setMargin(0);
    layout->setSpacing(0);
    grid->setLayout(layout);
    grid->setGeometry(500, 150, 240, 180);

    // following code is working, when run this program, 
    // i can see the 'w' widget with red background
    QWidget *w = new QWidget(grid);
    w->setStyleSheet("background:red;");
    layout->addWidget(w, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: `this->setCentralWidget(grid)` **Note:** Creating a main window without a central widget is not supported. You must have a central widget even if it is just a placeholder.

Comment: hi @Simon, i have a main_window.ui file, and it has a centralWidget already, the `grid` is one child widget in mainwindow

Comment: Is `ui.setupUi(this);` missing in the second code fragment on purpose?

Comment: hi @user6556709, sorry i just omit it, the difference with two code fragment is only `CustomWidget` and `QWidget`.

Comment: Can you provide the code for the `CustomWidget` class?  My guess would be that either 1) the constructor doesn't use the passed parameter `grid` as its parent or 2) `sizeHint` is returning a zero `QSize` (e.g. `QSize(0, 0)`).  But without seeing the code we can only guess.

Comment: I found the posible reason and a solution, see the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is said in the Qt's stylesheets reference, applying CSS styles to custom widgets inherited from QWidget requires reimplementing `paintEvent()` in that way:

```cpp
     void CustomWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
     {
         QStyleOption opt;
         opt.init(this);
         QPainter p(this);
         style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);
     }
```

Although for what it says in the documentation, *without doing it your custom widgets will support only the background, background-clip and background-origin properties*, for what might be a bug.

You can read about it here: [Qt Stylesheets reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html) in the section "List of Stylable Widgets" -> QWidget.